# HTML anchor only works in certain section

Tags: html

I am creating a website for my family business and have run into an issue. The "Photo Gallery" link in the navbar does not work, as if there is no target, but the link in the banner works perfectly fine. The other navbar links also work without issue.

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="top-nav">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Cafe</a>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse  collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right scroll">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="gallery.html" target="_blank">Photo Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#reviews">Customer Reviews</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#map">Map</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="home">
    <div class="banner">
        <img src="images/IMG_4030..jpg" alt="banner" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="caption">
            <div class="caption-wrapper">
                <div class="caption-info">
                    <i class="fa fa-coffee fa-5x animated bounceInDown"></i>
                    <h1 class="animated bounceInUp">Cafe</h1>
                    <p class="animated bounceInLeft">Hot coffee, bagels, sandwiches, platters, and catering.</p>
                    <a href="gallery.html" class="button">View Our Photo Gallery</a>
                    <br><br>
                    <a href="#menu" class="explore animated bounceInDown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down  fa-3x"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That is all of the relevant code... I am been looking on google but maybe I am searching the wrong tags. Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you import bootstrap?

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich yes, all of the imports come from cdn... both css and javascript

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any javascript handling the click event?  Could you share a link to the work in progress so we can evaluate exactly what is happening?

Comment: @ParrettApps unsure if linking is allowed, but... https://pastebin.com/ffkQE72j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem... check the console and it seems that its having trouble fetching the jquery script which is throwing everything off (running it on local windows).

Thank you @ParrettApps for pointing out javascript may be the issue

Edit:: Cant accept as answer... will in 2 days